# Finding complete and sufficient statistic for discrete distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

I have a single observation X from the following distribution:
$$P(X=-1) = \frac{p}{3}, P(X=0) = (1-p), P(X=1) = \frac{2p}{3}$$
I'm trying to prove that there is no complete and sufficient statistic for p based on the single observation X, but I'm getting a bit lost on how to do it since it's tricky to show that an estimator can be just one but not the other. Any hints on how to approach this?